# Which of these functions $f(x,y)$ can be extended to be continuous at $(0,0)$? And for the ones that are find a $\delta$ value.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Which of these functions $f(x,y)$ can be extended to be continuous at $(0,0)$? And for the ones that are find a $\delta$  such that $|f(x,y) - f(0,0)| < \epsilon$ when $|(x,y) - (0,0)| < \delta$.

a) $$\frac{|x-y|}{x^{2} - 2xy + y^{2}}$$

b) $$|x|^{y}$$

c) $$|x|^{\frac{1}{|y|}}$$

At first I didn't think this would be a challenge, but these are some nasty looking functions to at least think about. The first thing to clarify is that a multivariate function $f(\textbf{x})$ is continuous if $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}f(x,y) = f(0,0)$$, in this particular case.  So perhaps the first thing I should do if possible is try and find the value of $f(0,0)$ for each of the respective functions. I attempted such and I will explain the results in each part following. I'll give the thought process I've take which each function and as far as I've gotten.

**a)** this expression can be rewritten as $$\frac{|x - y|}{(x-y)^{2}}$$

Now the issue is to deal with the absolute value bars. I thought to split into two cases. If my approach is correct the second case will be symmetric to this case.

Case 1:

$$\frac{-(x-y)}{(x-y)^{2}} = \frac{-1}{(x-y)}\  \text{taking the limit of this expression}:$$  $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}f(x,y) = \Bigg\{ \begin{array} --\infty & \text{if}\ x < y \\ \infty & \text{if}\ y < x \\ \end{array}  $$

This being the case this function cannot be continuous at $(0,0)$.

**b)** I feel that this function is continuous as it is a composition of continuous functions in one variable. But Looking for some expression at $f(0,0)$ will lead me to an indeterminant form so I am struggling at what else I can do.

**c)** The same issue arises as with b), if I look at the function at $f(0,0)$ the fraction in the power would make this function undefined.

**My question:** What should I be doing to anaylze these functions and get more rigourous  conclusions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) $x^2-2xy+y^2=(x-y)^2$ this implies that if $x\neq y$, $f(x,y)={1\over{|x-y|}}$ and cannot be continuouly extended at $(0,0)$

For the second, $f(x)=e^{ylog|x|}$ if $x=y$, $lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x,x)=0$.

Write $y_n={1\over n}, x_n={1\over{2^n}}$, $lim_nf(x_n,y_n)={1\over 2}$,  so function cannot be extended

Comment: How did the denominator turn into an absolute value?

Comment: $(x-y)^2=|x-y|^2$

Comment: When I simplified it I felt I was missing something w.r.t.absolute  values and squaring. What about the other expressions?